# QGIS raster style rendering incorrectly/unexpectedly

Tags: qgis, raster, style

I have a raster of flow accumulation. To style it, when I set manual values for raster breaks in qgis 2.14 it isn't rendering all values below the value I set in the same colour. My understanding is that all cells below a value level take that colour; however, here the values of the cell remain uncoloured even though they fall below the value I've put in.

When I check the values of the pixels that aren't rendering in colour they are below the value I used. For example, I set the value to 5.13e+11, while the cell in the figure below has a value of 8.19e+9. Shouldn't the values in the high accumulation areas also then become pink (yes, apologies for the hideous pink colour...).

Any ideas where I'm going wrong or what the problem is?

[image: A single value break using the max value in the raster]

[image: High value pixels are still not rendering with the colour]

I've tried the same styling in QGIS 2.10 and it works as expected. I assume it's a bug in QGIS 2.14 and have submitted a report (http://hub.qgis.org/issues/14689).

Comment: Can you add a link to the bug report? It may be a good reference for future readers.

Comment: Indeed. Cheers for the advice.